# AEM 6.0 | Customize User Admin Console

Tags: aem, user-administration

We are trying to customize the user editor console provided out of the box from AEM (AEM 6.0 SP3, Touch UI).  However our changes are not reflected.

**Expected**: The new fields provided (see provided code segtment below) are shown, merged via the resource merger into the out of the box fields.

**Actual**: The new fields are not shown.

The overlay xml segment (userdetails) is found below (/apps/granite/security/content/userEditor/.content.xml):

```
<userdetails
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container"
    class="well user-details-sections-margin">
    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <extendedInfoContainer
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container"
            class="extended-container">
            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <linkedin
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                    class="save-button-enabler"
                    fieldLabel="LinkedIn"
                    name="./profile/linkedin"
                    value=""/>
                <twitter
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                    class="save-button-enabler"
                    fieldLabel="Twitter"
                    name="./profile/twitter"
                    value=""/>
                <xing
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                    class="save-button-enabler"
                    fieldLabel="xing"
                    name="./profile/xing"
                    value=""/>
                <photo
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/pathbrowser"
                    rootPath="/content/dam/arvato"
                    class="save-button-enabler"
                    fieldLabel="Profile photo"
                    name="./profile/photo"
                    value=""/>
            </items>
        </extendedInfoContainer>
    </items>
</userdetails>
```

We followed the instructions found in : https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/extending/customizing-consoles-touch.html

The same approach has worked fine in different projects, using AEM 6.2.

Answer (score 0):

why are you spending time in building a console which will be used only by admins? Its not a feature used by end users or your content authors. There is no point in building a fancy console. I am pretty sure newer versions of AEM will have a better console OOTB. AEM 6.3 already has a touch ui user admin console.  AEM will retire classic UI consoles completely by 6.4. I would recommend just wait for Adobe upgrades especially because there is not much use of this console.

Comment: I am sorry, I fail to understand how is this related to the question above. 

A User Admin console is a feature used by the user admins and is part of the usage scope of even the simplest CMSs. We're not building a new console, we are trying to extend an existing one.

Also, the User Admin Touch UI console exists in AEM6.0 already and the question is not even remotely related to ClassicUI.

I appreciate you taking the time to write a reply but I don't see the link to the original question.